# Transforming from a XML Schema type to an other with XQuery

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery

I try to find out, how to transform an extended ("extension") XML Schema element to the form of the original element. The example scenario is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/address"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:add="http://www.example.com/address"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

 <complexType name="Address">
   <sequence>
     <element name="name" type="string"/>
     <element name="street" type="string"/>
     <element name="city" type="string"/>
   </sequence>
 </complexType>

 <complexType name="UKAddress">
   <complexContent>
     <extension base="add:Address">
       <sequence>
         <element name="postcode" type="ipo:UKPostcode"/>
       </sequence>
       <attribute name="exportCode" type="positiveInteger" fixed="1"/>
     </extension>
   </complexContent>
 </complexType>

 <simpleType name="UKPostcode">
    <restriction base="string">
        <pattern value="[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][A-Z]{2}"/>
    </restriction>
 </simpleType>

 <element name="UKAddress" type="add:UKAddress" />
 <element name="Address" type="add:Address" />
</schema>
```

This is the Schema, and I try to transfrom this:

```
<UKAddress xmlns="http://www.example.com/address" exportCode="1">
    <name>Address1</name>
    <street>Example street</street>
    <city>London</city>
    <postcode>AA00 0AA</postcode>
</UKAddress>
```

Into this:

```
<UKAddress xmlns="http://www.example.com/address">
    <name>Address1</name>
    <street>Example street</street>
    <city>London</city>
</UKAddress>
```

Not with transform all of the children element one by one (this works well), but using some generic way, like cast. The main point is to somehow using the inherit-like structure of the Address element(s), and avoiding the high couple between map (Xquery) and leaf-elements. I tried to find some cast function, but those are for primitives, I tried to use xsi:type and I tried to ask all children element, and filter them. I found no working way. Has anybody met with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had some rounds with the answer. At first, I tried to make an Xpath query, which filters the child elements to me, like this:

```
declare function xf:testAddress($uKAddress1 as element())
    as element() {
        let $UKAddress := $uKAddress1
        return
            <ns0:Address>
                {$UKAddress/*[local-name()=('name', 'street', 'city')]}
            <ns0:Address>
};
```

(local-name is important: simple name() will contain the namespace, or worst: a dummy namespace, if the engine uses things like this) The problem is, the right side of the expression is not dynamic, and the XQuery of course can't see the Schema without help. A possible way to solve this is the following script:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/XML_Schema_to_Instance

With this, I could make a dummy instance of the Address, and then I could use this instance to map the children. So it's a kind of solution, but I think, it's not the right way, and this comes with a lot of extra work at every request.